# Setting authorization levels using Rest Server extension for CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, rest, restful-authentication, levels

I'm using the Rest Server (https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver) extension for CodeIgniter and I'm struggling to find examples on how to set the authorization level within a method.

I've tried all of the following:

```
public function index_get()
{
    $this->methods['index']['level'] = 10;
    $this->methods['level'] = 10;
    $this->rest->level = 10;
    $this->level = 10;
}
```

With no luck. Examples appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following protected method needs to go at the top of the API controller. Here you can specify the authorization level for each method and the rate limit.

```
   protected $methods = array(
           'index_get' => array('level' => 10),
           'types_get' => array('level' => 10, 'limit' => 20),
   );
```